# Bug with parsing by Text::CSV_XS?

Tags: perl, module

Tried to use Text::CSV_XS to parse some logs.  However, the following code doesn't do what I expected -- split the line into pieces according to separator `" "`.

The funny thing is, if I remove the double quote in the string `$a`, then it will do splitting.

Wonder if it's a bug or I missed something.  Thanks!

```
use Text::CSV_XS;

$a = 'id=firewall time="2010-05-09 16:07:21 UTC"';

$userDefinedSeparator = Text::CSV_XS->new({sep_char => " "});
print "$userDefinedSeparator\n";
$userDefinedSeparator->parse($a);
my $e;
foreach $e ($userDefinedSeparator->fields) {
    print $e, "\n";
}
```

**EDIT:**

In the above code snippet, it I change the `=` (after `time`) to be a space, then it works fine.  Started to wonder whether this is a bug after all?

```
$a = 'id=firewall time "2010-05-09 16:07:21 UTC"';
```

Comment: Fun fact: if you `use Text::CSV;`, it will automatically use the XS version if available and fall back to `Text::CSV_PP` if not.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, I'd rather get an error message then a needless performance degrade.

Comment: @codingFun: Is there a reason you want to avoid `split / /, $a`?

Comment: If you turn on the [`auto_diag`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV#auto_diag) option, you will get the following helpful message when you call `parse`: `# CSV_XS ERROR: 2034 - EIF - Loose unescaped quote @ rec 0 pos 18`.

Comment: @Borodin, `split / /` (like your answer) doesn't return `('id=firewall', 'time="2010-05-09 16:07:21 UTC"')`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, thanks for the tip, how do I configure the parser to allow double-quote then?

Comment: Don't. What you're parsing isn't a CSV, so don't try to parse it like one. TLP and Borodin both gave good solutions to extract the key-value pairs from your input; use one of those.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I appreciate TLP and Borodin for helping out with a code snippet. However, my requirements are 1) split fast (`Text::ParseWords` is much slower than `Text::CSV_XS`) and 2) the logs are not always in the form of key-value pair format.

Comment: Ask a new question where you show *all possible* formats that you need to parse. If you're concerned about speed, mention that in your question, along with the *specific,* quantifiable reasons that such-and-such solution doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: Regarding your edit about adding a space between `time` and `"2010-05-09 16:07:21 UTC"`: no, that is not a bug. This was already mentioned in Borodin's answer, but in CSV land, `time="2010-05-09 16:07:21 UTC"` is an unquoted field containing un-escaped quote characters. That violates `Text::CSV`'s rules for what is considered a valid CSV. On the other hand, `time` is simply an unquoted field (perfectly valid) and `"2010-05-09 16:07:21 UTC"` is a quoted field (also perfectly valid).

Comment: Thanks @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, it makes sense. I didn't understand the answer by Borodin well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have confused the module by leaving both the quote character and the escape character set to double quote `"`, and then left them embedded in the fields you want to split.

Disable both `quote_char` and `escape_char`, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV_XS;

my $string = 'id=firewall time="2010-05-09 16:07:21 UTC"';

my $space_sep = Text::CSV_XS->new({
   sep_char    => ' ',
   quote_char  => undef,
   escape_char => undef,
});

$space_sep->parse($string);

for my $field ($space_sep->fields) {
    print "$field\n";
}
```

**output**

```
id=firewall
time="2010-05-09
16:07:21
UTC"
```

But *note* that you have achieved exactly the same things as `print "$_\n" for split ' ', $string`, which is to be preferred as it is both more efficient and more concise.

In addition, you must *always* `use strict` and `use warnings`; and *never* use `$a` or `$b` as variable names, both because they are used by `sort` and because they are meaningless and undescriptive.

---

**Update**

As `@ThisSuitIsBlackNot` points out, your intention is probably not to split on spaces but to extract a series of `key=value` pairs. If so then this method puts the values straight into a hash.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'id=firewall time="2010-05-09 16:07:21 UTC"';

my %data = $string =~ / ([^=\s]+) \s* = \s* ( "[^"]*" | [^"\s]+ ) /xg;

use Data::Dump;
dd \%data;
```

**output**

```
{ id => "firewall", time => "\"2010-05-09 16:07:21 UTC\"" }
```

---

**Update**

This program will extract the two `name=value` strings and print them on separate lines.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'id=firewall time="2010-05-09 16:07:21 UTC"';

my @fields = $string =~ / (?: "[^"]*" | \S )+ /xg;

print "$_\n" for @fields;
```

**output**

```
id=firewall
time="2010-05-09 16:07:21 UTC"
```

Comment: You can get the same result by setting [`allow_loose_quotes`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV#allow_loose_quotes), although it is equally useless as the other approaches since I assume the OP is trying to parse out key-value pairs as opposed to space-delimited fields.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Very true. I hadn't stepped back far enough to look at the problem and what might be intended. Thank you.

Comment: It can be difficult to divine the OP's intent with these XY problems. I'm of course only guessing, but I can't imagine `time="2010-05-09` being particularly useful. Anyway, you pointed out the error in the OP's code and gave an alternative approach, so I think this is a good answer.

Comment: Thanks @Borodin for the quick reply and the code.  I would like to see two lines `id=firewall` and `time="2010-05-09 16:07:21 UTC"`.  Can you modify the above script to output two lines?   perl function `split` is nice, but it doesn't observe double quote when splitting.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, yes, I intend to parse out key value pair if there is one. Thanks.

Comment: @codingFun: I've added to my answer to show you how to do that, but if you want to extract the name and value from each entry then the hash version has already done that for you.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not actually trying to parse csv data, you can get the time field by using [`Text::ParseWords`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::ParseWords), which is a core module in Perl 5. The benefit to using this module is that it handles quotes very well.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Text::ParseWords;

my $str = 'id=firewall time="2010-05-09 16:07:21 UTC"';
my @fields = quotewords(' ', 0, $str);
print Dumper \@fields;
my %hash = map split(/=/, $_, 2), @fields;
print Dumper \%hash;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'id=firewall',
          'time=2010-05-09 16:07:21 UTC'
        ];
$VAR1 = {
          'time' => '2010-05-09 16:07:21 UTC',
          'id' => 'firewall'
        };
```

I also included how you can make the data more accessible by adding it to a hash. Note that hashes cannot contain duplicate keys, so you need a new hash for each new `time` key.

Comment: thanks for the code snippet, seems that Text::ParseWords does the splitting in perl and hence much slower. Did a quick profiling, splitting this short string will take 22us.  Text::CSV_XS can do splitting much faster.

Comment: @codingFun Actually, I think you will find that it was demonstrated that `Text::CSV_XS` cannot do it properly at all, but that it could do that faster than pure perl solutions. I somehow doubt that those 22us actually makes a difference in your program, unless you do 1,000,000,000 of these operations daily. I showed you how to do it properly, which you might find is worthwhile.