# Fast parser for logs

Tags: perl

Need to parse some logs with space (`" "`) as separator and observe double or single quote.

For example

```
id=firewall time="2010-05-09 16:07:21 UTC" 1.1.1.1 ...
```

should be parsed as

```
id=firewall
time="2010-05-09 16:07:21 UTC"
1.1.1.1
```

The logs are

- are quite long and
- not necessarily in key=value format
- not necessarily in csv format:

Tried to use Text::CSV_XS because it's much faster than the pure perl based parsers.  However, the following code doesn't do what I expected because the logs are not valid csv string.

```
use Text::CSV_XS;

$a = 'id=firewall time="2010-05-09 16:07:21 UTC"';

$userDefinedSeparator = Text::CSV_XS->new({sep_char => " "});
print "$userDefinedSeparator\n";
$userDefinedSeparator->parse($a);
my $e;
foreach $e ($userDefinedSeparator->fields) {
    print $e, "\n";
}
```

Is there a fast parser that can parse logs mentioned above? Would be nice to configure Text::CSV_XS to do the desired parsing.

Thanks to @ThisSuitIsBlackNot who suggested rewriting this question.

Comment: It is not helpful to say what the logs aren't:  *"not necessarily in key=value format"*, *"not necessarily in csv format"*.  If you want useful answers you need to aim for describing in excruciating detail what format the logs ARE in.  Otherwise this question is too broad to answer.

Comment: If you are looking for "faster" solutions, you should give some baseline speed examples to compare with.

Comment: Is this a standard log file format, and if so, is there an existing parser that you can use (even if it's not in perl)?

Comment: Thanks guys for taking a look. Agree with you that the question was not formulated with great clarity.  The speed requirement is that the parsing should be done within a few micro-seconds.  Ideally I would like to be under 1us, but that may require XS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this in [my response to your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729126/bug-with-parsing-by-textcsv-xs#comment40228696_25729384) on my solution to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729126xs#comment40228696_25729384).

Here is the answer I gave before, together with the new data that you have shown in this question.

The problem I had with your previous question is that you showed nothing but `key=value` pairs, so I assumed that that was all you had in your data.

I hope this works for you.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'id=firewall time="2010-05-09 16:07:21 UTC" 1.1.1.1 ...';

my @fields = $string =~ / (?: "[^"]*" | \S )+ /xg;

print "$_\n" for @fields;
```

**output**

```
id=firewall
time="2010-05-09 16:07:21 UTC"
1.1.1.1
...
```

Comment: Thanks @Borodin, this regexp solves the problem and reasonably fast: 10us to parse an expression.

Comment: I really don't trust your quest for ever more speed. Until you have rolled that parsing process into a program that does what you need, you can't even begin looking for bottlenecks where you can speed things up. How big are your log files? In ten minutes you can process 60 million lines, which is huge for a log file. In any case, a program that reads from a disk file is almost certain to be limited by the disk speed, and nothing you can do with the algorithm will make a significant difference. TL;DR - finish your program before worrying about speed.

Comment: you are right, disk can be a huge bottleneck if you are look at 10ms of seek time. But you know, logs will come from network too, with a very high speed :-)

Comment: @codingFunq: Even so, it is very wrong to optimise your code before you have discovered whether it runs fast enough already, and where your optimisation efforts should be focussed. At this stage your primary concern should be the *clarity* and *functionality* of your programming.

Comment: good point. It's better to do a profiling (like `Devel::NYTProf`) before spending the time on optimization.

Answer (score 0):

I'm half certain that you're going to tell me more about the log format after I submit this answer but here goes.

Only you know what your logs look like. If their format is regular, you'll have an easier time parsing them.

But given what you've supplied, you can split on spaces into an array, and then regroup the timestamp:

```
 my $a = q(id=firewall time="2010-05-09 16:07:21 UTC" 1.1.1.1);
 my @f = split(/ /, $a);
 my $id = $f[0];
 my $time = join(' ', @f[1..3]));

 print "$id\n$time\n$f[4]\n";
```

Comment: Thanks Len for giving it a try. Part of the requirements is to observe the " " in the string.

Comment: In this particular case `my $time = join(' ', @f[1..3]));` will do the job. However, it's just one of the cases,  the string may look like `id=firewall date="2010-05-09" time="16:07:21" 1.1.1.1` or something totally different.  Thanks again for taking a look at it.